# jquery 405 (Method Not Allowed) for foreign users

Tags: php, jquery

I started our game website with online test. We tested it on users from our country and it worked as we expected.

Now we are opened to the whole world, not just for our country, but every user getting error in console after clicking START TEST.
`POST http://jowland.eu/questions.php 405 (Method Not Allowed)   jquery.min.js:2` and test is not loading after validating ingame name.

Test and whole script wrote my friend, but he is now busy and doesn't have time to fix it.

You can test the script here: http://jowland.eu/whitelist/ (for validating name you can use my "Jowany")
questions.php source https://pastebin.com/4DLRspLc
More countries test and errors https://pastebin.com/5i5b7JwF

Any idea how to fix this error and not loading test for foreign visitors?

Comment: You cannot just drop a block of code on us saying it does not work.

Comment: It's working here (Argentina): `Validation successful for user Jowany
script.js:68 m0K4EI+6iPfUtgG5VJ/5+c549MvmijRF0NUzLll0y20K5XWZLZdz6/kufaFD2lX/n6yc6A+z3AP6kNPEveAfgXYzQqbKsdxoqcY7jFi9a61ZaoLIyMs+irB7C1htG+z+ywT44qxZuIxYJ7bVbdWb+w==`

Comment: It's difficult to imagine a situation where "not allowed" is being triggered because of a country. I mean in application code, unless you have a middleware somewhere in your app that is filtering requests (kind of firewall). It might be something occurring in a top level layer, like the webserver.

Comment: @LucianoFantuzzi I mean, generating test is not working, after clicking "Start test", there should be question with 3 options as aswer, but there is only blank page.

Answer (score 1):

After validating the first time, button allow me to do it again, but request is different: `{"success":false,"payload":[],"error":{"code":403,"message":"Forbidden POST requests from foreign countries, please, allow it in site settings"}}`.

First request is a GET to `http://jowland.eu/commands.php?validate-nick=Jowany`
Second one is a POST to: `http://jowland.eu/questions.php`

You need to see the routing file to know what class->method is being used to handle that request. Can you post it? What framework are you using?

Comment: Sure I can https://pastebin.com/EfCQy1yE
I dont know what you mean by framework, like I have basic html knowledge, but this test script did my friend.

Comment: There's no method to handle a POST there. You are iterating over GET requests (`foreach ($_GET as $action => $value) {`). `$_GET` contains only GET data. You need to iterate over `$_POST` to handle that. Moreover, there's no route of action inside that foreach to handle a POST request. You are not using any framework (like Laravel, Zend, Symfony, etc) to handle your app, and that's not good at all.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) I will wait for my friend, if he can fix it. I will replace generated test with google form temporarily.